# Get username and hostname of client in a strus2 form

Tags: struts2

I have a form which takes client's user name and machine name. I want to display machine's username and hostname in a textfield as a default value. How can I set string values to `default_username` and `default_hostname` so that `<s:textfield value="default_username">` 
and `<s:textfield value="default_hostname">` will display defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are browsing them they must be at value stack when your page got displayed all you need to refer them inside your text-field using OGNL something like

```
<s:textfield value="%{default_username}" name=username>
```

make sure that the `default_username` should be in value-stack which means your action should have public getter and setter for `default_username`.

Additionally your question is not clear enough so a more detail about use-case will help to get better inputs.

Comment: I have put <s:textfield value="%{defaultUser}" label="User Name"/> in the form and have written set method for defaultUser which sets value as this.defaultUser = System.getProperty("user.name");. Still form displys nothing in textfield.

Comment: As far as I understand, I think set method would be called at server side right? How would it get client machines user name?

Comment: @psp are you planning to get this information at client side using JavaScript or any other way? can you explian

Comment: Yes. As I am very new to web technologies, I don't know what should be used..javascript\ajax?

Comment: better go for serverside,create a utility class and get whatever details you want to get about user machine/host and than can use the same in your jsp using OGNL.be careful if you client is behind a proxy you will not get the actual details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6645/discussion-between-psp-and-umesh-awasthi)